# Trouble in regular expression

Tags: python, regex

Matching G in 'Reference: G. ' using regular expression

I tried using this but error still occur

```
refresidue = re.compiler(r'(s/Reference: \ //n)')
```

Any other suggestions as I'm quite new in this. Any help is most appreciated.

'Reference: G. ' reference can be either A,C,G or T

I'm sorry about the confusion - what i would like to have is that the output only prints out the characters (A,C,G,T) instead of Reference:  .

This is my code

refresidue = re.compiler(r'(s/Reference: \ //n)')

a_matchref = refresidue.search(row[2])

if a_matchref is not None:

```
   a_matchref = a_matchref.group(1)
```

Comment: It's `re.compile`, not `re.compiler`.

Comment: If `G` doesn't contain `: `, you can split and take the second part using `mystr.split(': ')[1]`

Comment: Thanks for reminding, i realized the typo now. The error is there's nothing printed out but just whitespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing regex syntax from JavaScript (or some other regex flavor) and Python; and the regex itself is also quite strange. Also, `re.compile()` compiles a regex, it doesn't match it to anything.

Assuming you want to match a single alphanumeric character after the text `Reference:`, try the following:

```
refresidue = re.search(r"Reference:\s*(\w)", your_text_to_be_matched).group(1)
```

Comment: 'Reference: G. ' I'm sorry about the confusion - what i would like to have is the output only prints out the character G instead of reference

Comment: The regular expression works perfect for my coding, sorry for my stupidity, I realized the mistake caused now.

Comment: Thanks to @Tim Pietzcker                                   refresidue = re.compile(r'Reference:\s*(\w)')

a_matchref = refresidue.search(row[2])

if a_matchref is not None:

a_matchref = a_matchref.group(1)

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I resolved the problem step-by-step. Even after several years of experience with regexp, some particular syntaxes always escapes my mind. At such times, it's best to start with a short expression which absolutely should match what you want.

Let's use the `re` module.

```
>>> import re
```

Now what is the error?

```
>>> refresidue = re.compiler(r'(s/Reference: \ //n)')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'compiler'
```

Ah, so what attributes does the `re` module have?

```
>>> dir(re)
['DEBUG', 'DOTALL', 'I', 'IGNORECASE', 'L', 'LOCALE', 'M', 'MULTILINE', 'S',
 'Scanner', 'T', 'TEMPLATE', 'U', 'UNICODE', 'VERBOSE', 'X', '_MAXCACHE', '__all__',
 '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__version__', '_alphanum',
 '_cache', '_cache_repl', '_compile', '_compile_repl', '_expand', '_pattern_type',
 '_pickle', '_subx', 'compile', 'copy_reg', 'error', 'escape', 'findall', 'finditer',
 'match', 'purge', 'search', 'split', 'sre_compile', 'sre_parse', 'sub', 'subn', 'sys',
 'template']
```

So it must be `re.compile`

```
>>> refresidue = re.compile(r'(s/Reference: \ //n)')(re)
```

Ok, compilation complete. Let's use it to match the string.

```
>>> refresidue.match('Reference: G')
```

Nothing? Strip down the expression then.

```
>>> refresidue = re.compile(r'Reference:')
>>> refresidue.match('Reference: G')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7fe14701f030>
```

Of course it should match. How about adding the G?

```
>>> refresidue = re.compile(r'Reference: G')
>>> refresidue.match('Reference: G')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7fe14701f098>
```

Yes. I want the whole alphabet please.

```
>>> refresidue = re.compile(r'Reference: [A-Z]')
>>> refresidue.match('Reference: G')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7fe14701f030>
```

I also want to single out the letter.

```
>>> refresidue = re.compile(r'Reference: ([A-Z])')
>>> refresidue.match('Reference: G')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7fe1470b9738>
```

No problem so far. So how do I get at the parenthesized part?

```
>>> dir(refresidue.match('Reference: G'))
['__copy__', '__deepcopy__', 'end', 'expand', 'group', 'groupdict', 'groups', 'span', 'start']
```

`group` sounds like it.

```
>>> refresidue.match('Reference: G').group   
<built-in method group of _sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7fe1470b9738>
```

So it's a method. Let's try calling it.

```
>>> refresidue.match('Reference: G').group(0)
'Reference: G'
```

How about this?

```
>>> refresidue.match('Reference: G').group(1)
'G'
```

There, the G.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you after, but maybe you can add more examples about the kind of data your are matching-

```
import re
refresidue = re.compile(r'Reference: ([A-Z])')
```

You use the above like this:

```
>>>> refresidue.match("Reference: G").group(1)
'G'
```